# Issue using John The Ripper

Tags: hash, penetration-test, password-cracking, john-the-ripper, crunch

First things first, I'm a newbie so, bear with me...

I created a word list with a combination of a possible password for a certain user using Crunch (it's the dictionary output) and need to use John The Ripper to sort through all the possible combinations in the wordlist created for the password and display it, alongside the hash and also need to add the --format=nt option, since the hash came from a Windows system. The hash is saved on another file and is in the correct format. However, I'm having trouble with this, can't seem to figure this out and, for better understanding, here are the screenshots of what I did:

https://imgur.com/a/M13XC63

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you need.

Comment: Here's the instruction: Pass the wordlist to John the Ripper to crack the password for the user account.
Note: When using John the Ripper to both crack the hashes and display the passwords, you will need to add the --format=nt option, since these hashes came from a Windows system. Except everytime I pass it through Jonh, I get the error "No password hashes loaded" and am stuck.

Comment: It seems John disagrees with your opinion that the hashes are stored in the correct format

Comment: The hash is saved as "administrator:500:somelongntlmstring:::" , so it's correct and here are screenshots of the commands I used: https://imgur.com/a/M13XC63